# How to remove url reservation in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

During a recovery process I have uninstalled and re-installed Sql Server 2008 R2 a couple of times with different instance names. I have recovered the database and want to configure the report server the way it was before.
My problem occurs in Reporting Services Configuration Manager when I try to apply defaults for the web service url. I get this error:

> Reserving url http: //+:80 The Url has already been reserved.

How do I un-reserve the url so that it can be applied to the new installation?

Comment: Why you are specifying port in URL, simply try with "http://ip_or_domainname/ReportS"

Comment: @Aditya I am trying to set it up with the same settings as the original installation to avoid having to change firewalls and device settings. The original installation used default settings that specified port 80

Comment: I 'm facing the same problem, but i've changed the port and still with the same issue. Someone knows what it could be ? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

**Make sure your current binding isn't from IIS or another webserver process, as deleting it could cause... badness**

Ensure your old SSRS instance is completely uninstalled (as the uninstallation process *should* free these bindings).  Next, fire up a command prompt window in admin mode (must be in admin to delete), and do:

Check your existing reserved URLS:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

Delete the URLs you don't want, using the exact same values shown on the "Reserved URL" line from the "show" command:

```
netsh http delete urlacl URL=http://+:80
```

You might consider binding your next install to a more specific URL, as the current wildcard binding will take *all* web (port 80) traffic coming to the server.

Comment: Checked the existing reserved urls. I have `http://+:80/ReportServer/` and `http://+:80/ReportServer/`. This is what is entered if you select "All Assigned (Recommended)" in the drop down list. Are you sure that this binding will take all web traffic? I wouldn't expect the recommended option would do that?

Comment: this solved my problem! URL=http://+:80 was reserved so after I added the actual server address, SSRS shows 503 Service not available error. I had to delete all the reserved addresses to get SSRS back again. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try removing URL from rsreportserver.config file located at Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer.